# Mirror Modifier seemingly not exact

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I am currently modeling a character. The face has a mirror modifier on it (not applied yet), and the eyes have been mirrored (applied) and separated, with a lattice acting on each. The lattices have basically been mirrored, (I used Scale X -1), so I know they are the same. However, I noticed the eye sockets don't appear to match up horizontally. If you look at the picture, I have created a small green box that is mirrored, and you can see the difference in the eye socket. I also added the red lines for more reference points.[image: example] If you follow the red lines and the green box from left to right, you will notice that the right eye socket appears to be shifted down.[image]

Comment: Check that the center of all of your objects is not off and that there are no animations applied to any rigged characters.

Comment: Thank you @JudeDesir, it ended up being something else!

Answer (score 1):

I realized that somewhere in the modeling process, the skin and eye meshes had become very, very slightly rotated. This meant that my mirroring was also rotated.